# Está correto o uso de “quanto” em “tudo quanto é canto”?

Tags: uso-de-palavras, pronomes

Já ouvi várias vezes *tudo quanto é canto* (= *tudo que é canto* = *todo canto*), tanto que é generalizável, *tudo quanto é X*. Pesquisando no Google dos pronomes relativos (*quanto* é pronome relativo), apenas achei que *quanto* (como pronome relativo) é usado com outros significados, máxime de quantidade, como em *como tantas batatas quantas agüento* e *ela tem quanto precisa para comprar a casa*.

Então pergunto: é correto o uso de *quanto* como *que*?

Se bem me lembro, há desse uso na carta do descobrimento do Brasil e em outros textos antigos, de antes do século XVIII, então, talvez seja um arcaísmo.

Comment: “Sobre isto acordaram que não era necessário tomar por força homens, porque era geral costume dos que assim levavam por força para alguma parte dizerem que há ali de **tudo quanto** lhes perguntam”,  [Pero Vaz de Caminha, carta do descobrimento do Brasil](http://objdigital.bn.br/Acervo_Digital/livros_eletronicos/carta.pdf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olha só o que diz o **maior** poeta da língua portuguesa (penso eu), o Fernando Pessoa:

> Tudo quanto vive,
> vive porque muda; muda porque
> passa; e, porque passa,
> morre. Tudo quanto vive
> perpetuamente se torna
> outra coisa, constantemente
> se nega, se furta à vida.

Os sinónimos segundo este site ([tudo quanto](https://www.sinonimos.com.br/tudo-quanto/)) são:

> qualquer coisa, o que quer que seja, seja o que for, tudo aquilo que.

Conclusão: "tudo quanto é x" não é exatamente "tudo que é x". Se usa para dizer "qualquer coisa que é" e é **mais formal**. E "tudo quanto é conto" não equivale a "todo conto".

"Tudo quanto" contém uma dúvida. "Tudo que", não.

Se pode **sentir** no poema do Pessoa essa dúvida. Ele está dizendo que se o ser está vivo, daí vem um série de coisas. Mas ele não está dizendo que tudo vive. :)

---

Fernando Pessoa PESSOA, F. Livro do Desassossego, por Bernardo Soares. Vol. II. Mem Martins: Europa-América, 1986.

[tudo quanto](https://www.pensador.com/frase/MTEwMTg/)

Comment: Interessante. Camões também usou, segundo o Aulete, “ O que, aquilo: || Que o médico advertido tudo quanto deseja lhe consinta. (Camões.) ”. Então, *tudo quanto é cachorro* é *tudo aquilo que/o que é cachorro*, assim como *tudo quanto deseja* é *tudo aquilo que/o que deseja*. Eu tinha visto esse significado no Houaiss, mas não havia entendido. Obrigado pela resposta!

Comment: Achei outra coisa interessante. Acho que *tudo quanto* é expressão antiga na língua, porquanto ela era usada em textos em galego-português: http://glossa.gal/glosario/termo/2827#fc-loc_pronom-2. Agora não sei se o meu outro comentário estava certo.

Comment: Pra ser franco, não entendi bem isso de "tudo quanto é x" = "qualquer coisa que é x" ≠ "tudo que é x". Eu diria sem hesitação que as duas últimas expressões são intercambiáveis.

Comment: Achos que os votos negativos mostram que as pessoas não sabem ler.

Answer (score 3):

Todas estas variantes estão correctas e têm o mesmo significado:

- Há teias de aranha em **tudo quanto** é canto.
- Há teias de aranha em **tudo aquilo que** é canto.
- Há teias de aranha em **tudo o que** é canto.

É a alternativa que dás (*em tudo que é canto*) que me parece marginal (embora por alguma razão não tão má quanto ?*tudo que sei está errado*). Esta construção é contudo descrita como ["particularmente corrente" no português do Brasil](http://clul.ulisboa.pt/files/telmo_moia/tmoia_tesemestrado1992.pdf) (errata para a pág. 82).

Answer (score -1):

Segundo uma pesquisa que fiz, "tudo quanto é canto" e "tudo que é canto" estariam corretas por atenderem à demanda do sentido.

Comment: Por favor não deixe de citar tuas fontes na resposta — como está, é como se ela não as tivesse.